# make local installation of anaconda available to all users w/o having to install all again

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, anaconda

I installed anaconda on a user account under username ubuntu on a linux server running Ubuntu.

I then created new users in my ubuntu server, called let's say ubuntu1, ubuntu2, etc.

When I login as ubuntu I can do:

`conda activate <env_name>` and it will activate the python environment for the user called ubuntu.

The environment was installed under `/home/ubuntu/anaconda3`.  I.e., in the user local directory.

Is there a way to make this conda environment global for all users so when I login as a different user, let's say username ubuntu1, the conda activate works and the new user is also able to use the desired anaconda and python version?

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** I do not want to re-install anaconda, or create a yml file of existing anaconda and then re-install it as admin.  I would want to just use the current configuration/installation by making it widely available to the new users.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is to set the appropriate permissions to your environment path from the existing user, and change the `.bashrc` file (or `.profile`, or whatever you use as init script in the shell) of the new user to have the `conda` binaries available in your `$PATH`.

Of course, this may be a security risk for the user under which `anaconda` is installed to.